# "if defined" before declare a class is a good practice?

Tags: php, performance, code-readability

Repairing codes in my job I noticed that a lot of classes are declared after a check if something is defined, like:

```
<?
  if(!defined("_myClass_inc")){

      define("_myClass_inc", 1);

      class _myClass{
          __contructor(){
          //Code goes here
          }
      }
  }
?>
```

Is this the best way to do, considering that exists the function `require_once`?

Comment: `require_once` probably does something similar internally. Why re-invent the wheel? Of course PHP has also had autoloaders for quite a while now so `require_once` does not even need to be done explicitly.

Comment: [class_exists()](http://php.net/class_exists) might eliminate the need for the extra constant...